# YUI datatable is not getting refreshed with data from the server

Tags: datatable, refresh, yui

YUI datatable is not getting refreshed with data from the server.

I tried both the below options:

**OPTION 1:**

```
myDataTable.getDataSource().liveData = 'http://localhost:8080/YUIDemo/getRMADetails';

myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(null, { 
    success: function (oRequest, oResponse, oPayload) { YAHOO.log('got...'+oResponse.results.length);
    myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable;},  
    failure: function (){ YAHOO.log("table refresh failed");},
    scope: myDataTable}, myDataTable);
```

**OPTION 2:**

```
var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.XHRDataSource("http://localhost:8080/YUIDemo/getRMADetails");
myDataSource.responseType = YAHOO.util.DataSource.TYPE_JSARRAY;
myDataSource.responseSchema = {
    fields : [ "rma", "rmaLineNumber", "status", "statusDesc",
            "completeDate", "completeTime" ]
};

myColumnDefs = [ {key : "rma", label: "RMA", sortable : true, resizeable : true}, 
   {key : "rmaLineNumber", label: "RMA Line Number", sortable : true, resizeable : true}, 
   {key : "status", label: "Status", sortable : true, resizeable : true}, 
   {key : "statusDesc", label: "Status Desc", sortable : true, resizeable : true}, 
   {key : "completeDate", label: "Complete Date", sortable : true, resizeable : true}, 
   {key : "completeTime", label: "Complete Time", sortable : true, resizeable : true} ];

myDataTable = new YAHOO.widget.DataTable("basic", myColumnDefs, myDataSource,{caption:"Results"});

myDataTable.getDataSource().sendRequest(null, 
    {success: function (oRequest,oResponse,oPayload){YAHOO.log('got...'+oResponse.results.length);myDataTable.onDataReturnInitializeTable;}, 
    failure: function (){YAHOO.log("table refresh failed");},
    scope: myDataTable},myDataTable);
```

Comment: If I set the JSON Array manually it works:                          var RMAData = {details:[]}; var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource(RMAdata.details);                                                                                                 But when the same data is received from the server it gives "Data error":                                                             var myDataSource = new YAHOO.util.DataSource("http://localhost:8080/YUIDemo/getRMADetails"); // Or XHRDataSource

Comment: what is getRMADetails exactly ? where is it defined ?

Answer (score 0):

You shouldn't give it `http://localhost:8080/YUIDemo/getRMADetails` instead give it just the relative path to where getRMADetails is depending and where is your javascript file.

also make sure that data you're that are returned from getRMADetails have keys that match fields in your datasource's responseSchema.